# Unable to copy one buffer into another in node JS

Tags: node.js, buffer

I want to copy some elements of my one buffer in another buffer. I typed following command on REPL

```
assn1.copy(assn3,0,40,59)
```

assn1 is source buffer assn3 is target buffer

but I am getting following error.

```
TypeError: assn1.copy is not a function
at repl:1:7
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:270:27)
at bound (domain.js:287:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:439:10)
at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:182:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:550:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:827:14)
```

help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Is 'assn1' is really a 'Buffer' type?

Comment: yes it is. I declared it as,var assn1=new Buffer(100)

Comment: @NeoAsh after that I copied an array in that buffer using assn1=arr; and after that it is giving false to Buffer.isBuffer(assn1)

Comment: Might be `assn1` not accessible.

Try to log `assn1` value by using `console.log(assn1.toString());`.

Comment: @NeoAsh it is printing the output but it got converted in array it is no more buffer after copying array into it

Comment: i.e. `arr` is not the type of array. That's why copy method is available for `assn1`.

Answer (score 0):

assn1=arr;

is not actually copying an array into the buffer, instead re-assigning a variable to an array object, and by doing so you lost the buffer object.

Try something like this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 8, 9];
var buf1 = new Buffer(a);
var b = [3, 4];
new Buffer(b).copy(buf1, 2, 0, 2);
console.log(buf1);
```

Provides me this output:

```
<Buffer 01 02 03 04>
```

Hope this helps.